# Android XML Class Cast Exception TextView

Tags: android, xml, textview, classcastexception

I'm getting this fatal exception :

```
02-01 14:48:24.310: E/AndroidRuntime(12835): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prva/com.example.prva.Meni_Splash}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
```

I don't understand where is the problem in my textview? I've only tried to change the TimePickers position so its under textDate textview?

Here is my complete .xml.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/menu">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/pozdrav"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Date/Time"
        android:textSize="25sp" />    

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:layout_below="@id/textDate"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnalarm"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_below="@id/timePicker"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerPoint"
        android:text="@string/postavi"  />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttoncancel"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_below="@id/timePicker" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/centerPoint"     
        android:text="@string/zaustavi" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/centerPoint"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/timePicker"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonv"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_below="@id/btnalarm"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_v"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text="@string/buttonv"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />    

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonv1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/buttonv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_v"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text="@string/buttonv1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textbaza"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/buttonv1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="@string/textbaza" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnlistview"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/buttonv1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/buttonv1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="ListView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `layout_below` don't give `@+id/` because it will create a new id. better avoid this.

```
   android:layout_below="@id/textDate"
```

This should be correct.

All also **clean your project and build again**.

Answer (score 2):

Not a big issue just clean your project and close Eclipse  Reopen it and run your app it will work fine

Comment: You're right. Can I ask you, while we are here, I can't put my TimePicker under the txtDate TextView, TimePicker always place itself over the txtDate but under the textView1?

Comment: did not check that thing Explicitly but that error you are referencing occurs some time but handled the same way i told